# How do I create a leading debounce with redux-saga

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga, debouncing

Is there a way to do a leading debounce?

The example on the recipes only shows a trailing debounce. So below is trailing debounce example where we delay the logic fro 500ms:

```
import { call, cancel, fork, take, delay } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* handleInput(input) {
  // debounce by 500ms
  yield delay(500)
  ...
}

function* watchInput() {
  let task
  while (true) {
    const { input } = yield take('INPUT_CHANGED')
    if (task) {
      yield cancel(task)
    }
    task = yield fork(handleInput, input)
  }
}
```

where as i'd like to execute logic on the first call that cancel any subsequent calls until 500ms has ended.

**Edit**

This can be done by using `takeLeading` then delaying the saga at the end by however long you want to debounce for.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by using `takeLeading` then delaying the saga at the end by however long you want to debounce for.